# How to set-up EF to not to let saveChanges if the previously loaded entity is modified on the Db?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

1. I load an entity via EF
2. I hit a break point in my code
3. and modify the loaded entity via SQL Server Management Studio on the Database
4. I hit F5 and call base.SaveChanges()

My expectation is EF would throw an exception as the entity is different on Db than the one it was loaded loaded.

**QUESTION:**
What should I do so that in the time of saving changes EF would check the properties that are not modified on entity are different in the Db so that it prevents the Save by throwing an exception?

Answer (score 1):

What you need are concurrency checks.

In Entity Framework, every entity property has a `Concurrency Mode`. If you change this mode to `Fixed`, that entity property will be checked for when updating data.

One thing you may do to make this easier to use is to include a `Timestamp` property, set its Concurrency Mode to Fixed, and then create a `TRIGGER` in SQL Server to update the `Timestamp` field every time a record is updated.

Then you won't need to put the Concurrency Mode of any other entity property to Fixed, as any change in a database record -- whether by saving via Entity Framework or any other means -- will cause the `Timestamp` to be updated and any `Save` operation after that in Entity Framework will check the value of that `Timestamp`. This mechanism is called Optimistic Concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in [Refresh Method.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896255%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Also have a look at [Save changes and Managing concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738618%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You might find it useful.